# While committing the file to GitHub.It is not taking the user.name configured to Git. And instead using the username of GitHub. Why is it so?

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio, git-commit

I have used **"themisslady"** as my username for GitHub.
In Git, I have configured the following user.name to Git, using this command----
**git config global user.name "Miss lady"**. The email id configured with Git is same as that of GitHub.

I am using RStudio and while committing the file from within RStudio to GitHub, I am getting this notification-------themisslady committed the file xyz. While I thought it should have said -----Miss lady committed the file xyz.

> git version---2.27.0.windows.1

> Rstudio version-----
>
> R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Please answer why is it happening like this.

Comment: Check source control settings in RStudio. I wonder if it has a separate username configured for git.

Comment: Where are you seeing this notification?  Is it coming from GitHub or RStudio itself?

Comment: Does it happens if you commit from terminal aswell?

Answer (score 1):

There could be some problem with your config file. Please run in Terminal, PowerShell or Windows CMD:

```
 git config --list
```

and check that your user name is really there.

If not, run again:

```
git config --global user.name "Miss lady"
```

(maybe there seems to be a typo in your command: missing two dashes before global?).

But note that GitHub shows user logins instead of configured user names on some places: look at [this Hadley Wickham's commit](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/d5a28b2c76325cc92201937468d5a4420b895df0) that says "hadley commited..." while if you open the [raw patch](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/d5a28b2c76325cc92201937468d5a4420b895df0.patch), you see that his name is properly configured.